# Blazor server cookie authentication works on my local IIS but not on server IIS

Tags: iis, blazor

I have a blazor server website that uses cookie authentication.
It all works fine on my pc but when I deploy to another server IIS the logs say:

On my local IIS:
AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
...
AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.

On the server IIS:
AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
...
AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was not authenticated.

I googled and used chatGpt but got only vague directions to check the IIS settings.

The session state on both IIS is the same.

What settings should I look at?
Is there something in the logs that I should pay more attention to?

EDIT: I'm using Razor pages for the login that allows me to sign in to the HttpContext.

```
 var claims = new List<Claim>{new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "test")};
 var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
 var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

 await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
```

EDIT2:
I've cut the website down to only login functionality, turned it on, logged in and turned off. These are the logs created by Blazor:

### Server logs:

(IIS version 7.5.7600.16385)

```
[INF] User profile not available. Using 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\4.0.30319.0\AutoGenKeys\S-1-5-82-2448206185-2076038333-680349695-2793760149-3118516866\DataProtection' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
[INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[INF] Hosting environment: Production
[INF] Content root path: C:\inetpub\AutoAdmin
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/ - -
[WRN] Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
[INF] Executing endpoint '/_Host'
[INF] Route matched with {page = "/_Host", area = ""}. Executing page /_Host
[INF] Executing an implicit handler method - ModelState is "Valid"
[INF] Executed an implicit handler method, returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageResult.
[INF] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
[INF] Executed page /_Host in 415.4829ms
[INF] Executed endpoint '/_Host'
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/ - - - 200 - text/html;+charset=utf-8 612.5246ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css - -
[INF] The file /css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css was not modified
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/site.css - -
[INF] The file /css/site.css was not modified
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css - - - 304 - text/css 13.8614ms
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/site.css - - - 304 - text/css 4.5469ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/AutoAdmin.styles.css - -
[INF] Sending file. Request path: '/AutoAdmin.styles.css'. Physical path: 'C:\inetpub\AutoAdmin\wwwroot\AutoAdmin.styles.css'
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/AutoAdmin.styles.css - - - 200 3483 text/css 9.5096ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/_framework/blazor.server.js - -
[INF] The file /_framework/blazor.server.js was not modified
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/_framework/blazor.server.js - - - 304 - text/javascript 2.1693ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css - -
[INF] The file /css/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css was not modified
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css - - - 304 - text/css 1.5143ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.eot? - -
[INF] The file /css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.eot was not modified
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.eot? - - - 304 - application/vnd.ms-fontobject 1.7585ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.woff - -
[INF] The file /css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.woff was not modified
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.woff - - - 304 - application/font-woff 1.6434ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/Identity/Account/Login - -
[INF] Executing endpoint '/Account/Login'
[INF] Route matched with {page = "/Account/Login", area = "Identity"}. Executing page /Account/Login
[INF] Executing handler method AutoAdmin.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel.OnGet - ModelState is "Valid"
[INF] Executed handler method OnGet, returned result .
[INF] Executing an implicit handler method - ModelState is "Valid"
[INF] Executed an implicit handler method, returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageResult.
[INF] Executed page /Account/Login in 133.4199ms
[INF] Executed endpoint '/Account/Login'
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/Identity/Account/Login - - - 200 - text/html;+charset=utf-8 192.4903ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/Identity/Account/-/css/site.css - -
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/Identity/Account/—/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css - -
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/Identity/Account/—/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css - - - 404 - - 16.3509ms
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/Identity/Account/-/css/site.css - - - 404 - - 17.0178ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:90/Identity/Account/Login application/x-www-form-urlencoded 222
[INF] Executing endpoint '/Account/Login'
[INF] Route matched with {page = "/Account/Login", area = "Identity"}. Executing page /Account/Login
[INF] Executing handler method AutoAdmin.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel.OnPostAsync - ModelState is "Valid"
[INF] AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
[INF] Executed handler method OnPostAsync, returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.LocalRedirectResult.
[INF] Executing LocalRedirectResult, redirecting to /.
[INF] Executed page /Account/Login in 59.5123ms
[INF] Executed endpoint '/Account/Login'
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:90/Identity/Account/Login application/x-www-form-urlencoded 222 - 302 - - 63.0868ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/ - -
[INF] Executing endpoint '/_Host'
[INF] Route matched with {page = "/_Host", area = ""}. Executing page /_Host
[INF] Executing an implicit handler method - ModelState is "Valid"
[INF] Executed an implicit handler method, returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageResult.
[INF] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
[INF] Executed page /_Host in 20.8163ms
[INF] Executed endpoint '/_Host'
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/ - - - 200 - text/html;+charset=utf-8 24.3812ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css - -
[INF] The file /css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css was not modified
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/site.css - -
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css - - - 304 - text/css 0.7474ms
[INF] The file /css/site.css was not modified
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/AutoAdmin.styles.css - -
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/site.css - - - 304 - text/css 0.8411ms
[INF] The file /AutoAdmin.styles.css was not modified
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/_framework/blazor.server.js - -
[INF] The file /_framework/blazor.server.js was not modified
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/_framework/blazor.server.js - - - 304 - text/javascript 0.5582ms
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/AutoAdmin.styles.css - - - 304 - text/css 1.8631ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css - -
[INF] The file /css/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css was not modified
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css - - - 304 - text/css 0.8663ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.eot? - -
[INF] The file /css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.eot was not modified
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.eot? - - - 304 - application/vnd.ms-fontobject 0.8887ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.woff - -
[INF] The file /css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.woff was not modified
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.woff - - - 304 - application/font-woff 1.0036ms
[INF] Application is shutting down...
```

### Local IIS logs:

(IIS version 10.0.19041.1)

```
[INF] User profile not available. Using 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\4.0.30319.0\AutoGenKeys\S-1-5-82-2448206185-2076038333-680349695-2793760149-3118516866\DataProtection' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
[INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[INF] Hosting environment: Production
[INF] Content root path: C:\inetpub\AutoAdmin
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/ - -
[WRN] Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
[INF] Executing endpoint '/_Host'
[INF] Route matched with {page = "/_Host", area = ""}. Executing page /_Host
[INF] Executing an implicit handler method - ModelState is "Valid"
[INF] Executed an implicit handler method, returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageResult.
[INF] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
[INF] Executed page /_Host in 135.9531ms
[INF] Executed endpoint '/_Host'
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/ - - - 200 - text/html;+charset=utf-8 185.2786ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css - -
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/site.css - -
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/AutoAdmin.styles.css - -
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/_framework/blazor.server.js - -
[INF] The file /css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css was not modified
[INF] The file /css/site.css was not modified
[INF] The file /AutoAdmin.styles.css was not modified
[INF] The file /_framework/blazor.server.js was not modified
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/AutoAdmin.styles.css - - - 304 - text/css 15.3890ms
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/_framework/blazor.server.js - - - 304 - text/javascript 15.0205ms
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/site.css - - - 304 - text/css 17.7972ms
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css - - - 304 - text/css 19.0347ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css - -
[INF] The file /css/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css was not modified
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css - - - 304 - text/css 0.7360ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/_blazor/initializers - -
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.woff - -
[INF] The file /css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.woff was not modified
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.woff - - - 304 - application/font-woff 0.8699ms
[INF] Executing endpoint 'Blazor initializers'
[INF] Executed endpoint 'Blazor initializers'
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/_blazor/initializers - - - 200 - application/json;+charset=utf-8 8.6959ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:90/_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 - 0
[INF] Executing endpoint '/_blazor/negotiate'
[INF] Executed endpoint '/_blazor/negotiate'
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:90/_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 - 0 - 200 316 application/json 10.4820ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/_blazor?id=Y9dADrlVMOF21b2SY2_llw - -
[INF] Executing endpoint '/_blazor'
[INF] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
[INF] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/Identity/Account/Login - -
[INF] Executing endpoint '/Account/Login'
[INF] Executed endpoint '/_blazor'
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/_blazor?id=Y9dADrlVMOF21b2SY2_llw - - - 101 - - 1331.8554ms
[INF] Route matched with {page = "/Account/Login", area = "Identity"}. Executing page /Account/Login
[INF] Executing handler method AutoAdmin.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel.OnGet - ModelState is "Valid"
[INF] Executed handler method OnGet, returned result .
[INF] Executing an implicit handler method - ModelState is "Valid"
[INF] Executed an implicit handler method, returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageResult.
[INF] Executed page /Account/Login in 43.5721ms
[INF] Executed endpoint '/Account/Login'
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/Identity/Account/Login - - - 200 - text/html;+charset=utf-8 57.2322ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:90/_blazor/disconnect multipart/form-data;+boundary=---------------------------81701742221890047431941658524 395
[INF] Executing endpoint 'Blazor disconnect'
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/Identity/Account/-/css/site.css - -
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/Identity/Account/—/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css - -
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/Identity/Account/-/css/site.css - - - 404 - - 3.6273ms
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/Identity/Account/—/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css - - - 404 - - 3.3918ms
[INF] Executed endpoint 'Blazor disconnect'
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:90/_blazor/disconnect multipart/form-data;+boundary=---------------------------81701742221890047431941658524 395 - 200 - - 13.5431ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/favicon.ico - -
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/favicon.ico - - - 0 - - 1.7014ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:90/Identity/Account/Login application/x-www-form-urlencoded 222
[INF] Executing endpoint '/Account/Login'
[INF] Route matched with {page = "/Account/Login", area = "Identity"}. Executing page /Account/Login
[INF] Executing handler method AutoAdmin.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel.OnPostAsync - ModelState is "Valid"
[INF] AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
[INF] Executed handler method OnPostAsync, returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.LocalRedirectResult.
[INF] Executing LocalRedirectResult, redirecting to /.
[INF] Executed page /Account/Login in 16.4811ms
[INF] Executed endpoint '/Account/Login'
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:90/Identity/Account/Login application/x-www-form-urlencoded 222 - 302 - - 17.7695ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/ - -
[INF] Executing endpoint '/_Host'
[INF] Route matched with {page = "/_Host", area = ""}. Executing page /_Host
[INF] Executing an implicit handler method - ModelState is "Valid"
[INF] Executed an implicit handler method, returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageResult.
[INF] Executed page /_Host in 5.6317ms
[INF] Executed endpoint '/_Host'
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/ - - - 200 - text/html;+charset=utf-8 7.9873ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/_framework/blazor.server.js - -
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css - -
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/site.css - -
[INF] The file /_framework/blazor.server.js was not modified
[INF] The file /css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css was not modified
[INF] The file /css/site.css was not modified
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/_framework/blazor.server.js - - - 304 - text/javascript 0.8444ms
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/site.css - - - 304 - text/css 0.8814ms
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css - - - 304 - text/css 1.0526ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/AutoAdmin.styles.css - -
[INF] The file /AutoAdmin.styles.css was not modified
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/AutoAdmin.styles.css - - - 304 - text/css 0.6659ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css - -
[INF] Sending file. Request path: '/css/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css'. Physical path: 'C:\inetpub\AutoAdmin\wwwroot\css\open-iconic\font\css\open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css'
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/css/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css - - - 200 9395 text/css 6.5666ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/_blazor/initializers - -
[INF] Executing endpoint 'Blazor initializers'
[INF] Executed endpoint 'Blazor initializers'
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/_blazor/initializers - - - 200 - application/json;+charset=utf-8 1.2535ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/favicon.png - -
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:90/_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 - 0
[INF] Executing endpoint '/_blazor/negotiate'
[INF] Executed endpoint '/_blazor/negotiate'
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:90/_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 - 0 - 200 316 application/json 1.0436ms
[INF] Sending file. Request path: '/favicon.png'. Physical path: 'C:\inetpub\AutoAdmin\wwwroot\favicon.png'
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/favicon.png - - - 0 1148 image/png 10.4905ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/_blazor?id=pFVhZPCkb_r9oIZxtOJ74A - -
[INF] Executing endpoint '/_blazor'
[INF] Executed endpoint '/_blazor'
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:90/_blazor?id=pFVhZPCkb_r9oIZxtOJ74A - - - 101 - - 4816.3952ms
[INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:90/_blazor/disconnect multipart/form-data;+boundary=---------------------------11063778403973626042017606463 395
[INF] Executing endpoint 'Blazor disconnect'
[INF] Executed endpoint 'Blazor disconnect'
[INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:90/_blazor/disconnect multipart/form-data;+boundary=---------------------------11063778403973626042017606463 395 - 200 - - 2.5265ms
[INF] Application is shutting down...
```

Comment: Do you use a middleware to set the cookies ? It would be nice, if you could provide some of your settings, so we can help you out.

Comment: I am setting the cookies from code using Razor pages to SignIn to the Httpcontext.

See the edit in post.

I could post a link to github if that would help.
Considering the IIS settings. I'm not sure how to convey that.

Comment: IIS logs as documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/configure-logging-in-iis only record very basic HTTP fields and never touch something like "AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in. ... AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was not authenticated." So what exactly is the log you are talking about? If you describe an issue wrongly, neither an AI nor human can help.

Comment: Check local and server IIS configurations. Is there any other error message here? Current with vague information, community members can hardly help you.

Comment: There are no errors in the IIS logs, the logs I posted (edit2) are from the blazor app itself. Is it possible that the server IIS is simply too old? (it's from 2008)

Comment: It is indeed too old, it should end its lifecycle in 2020. After end of support, you’re at risk of your applications and servers no longer fulfilling their business objective. Then you should test with a supported IIS server.